# Disable (Close) webform form dynamically

Tags: webforms

We would like to be able to put our site into a "read-only" mode prior to doing major releases etc. I was hoping to achieve this for forms on the site by enabling or disabling my custom module, which I could easily do from drush during our release process.

The module would use a hook to disable all forms and show the closed message instead.

This is what I had so far:

```
<?php

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

/**
 * Implementation of hook_form_alter().
 *
 * Disables any webforms when this module is active. Include a custom config key
 * called `exempt_from_maintenance_mode` with any value to allow your form to
 * remain open during maintenance.
 *
 * E.g.
 *     exempt_from_maintenance_mode: 1
 *
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
 */
function yvw_maintenance_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id)
{
    // Check for custom config key
    if (array_key_exists('#exempt_from_maintenance_mode', $form)) {
        return;
    }

    // Load the webform entity. This should prevent the module from disabling
    // all forms across the site.
    $webform_id = $form['#webform_id'];
    $webform = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('webform')->load($webform_id);

    // Only disable the webform if its currently enabled
    if ($webform->status() === true) {
        $webform->setStatus('closed');
        // Does not save. Maybe we need a different hook.
    }
}
```

The problem is I would need to call $webform->save(); which would permanently close the form. I was hoping there was a hook where I could modify the form configuration only at runtime, and not persist any of the changes to the database. But I haven't been able to find any hooks that look like they would do it.

I had a look at [Close a webform when total seats reach a maximum](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/258089/close-a-webform-when-total-seats-reach-a-maximum) which is close to what I want, but it appears that would only run on submission, and also permanently closes the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Webforms are config entities and you can use [hook_webform_load()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_load) to close the webform before it is rendered and then altered. Instead of closing and resaving the webform, you can call `$webform->setPropertyOverride('status', FALSE);` which will safely close the webform and prevent it from being permanently closed.

Comment: Thanks so much! That is exactly what I needed.