# How do I programmatically close webform by node date field?

Tags: webforms

**Background:** 
I'm adding an events (custom content type) & registrations feature to an existing drupal 8 website. *My experience in drupal is pretty minimal.* But I can find my ways around code.

These events can be conferences, seminars, training spanning 1-N days with N number of seats.

**What I have got so far** is creating content type & referencing webform.

**What I want**
Ways to disable/close form before event starts or as per a date field (ie, registration will be disabled).

**What I have found** which looks pretty close to what I want

[Disable (Close) webform form dynamically](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/277355/disable-close-webform-form-dynamically)

[Close a webform when total seats reach a maximum](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/258089/close-a-webform-when-total-seats-reach-a-maximum)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this module, but you might look at "Scheduled Updates"

Here's a walk through:
https://www.mediacurrent.com/blog/scheduling-content-changes-drupal-8/