# webforms Submission limit in event registration when it's possible to registrate more than 1 person by form

Tags: webforms

I use "Webform Demo: Event Registration System", to manage event registration, and everything works perfectly if only one person can subscribe in a Form.

For example I want to stop the registration if they are more than 100 peoples, and when a person subscribe, he can come with his wife. So the limit I put in :

entity_limit_total: '[webform_submission:node:field_free_places]'

is wrong. How can I did it ?

Comment: See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/258089/close-a-webform-when-total-seats-reach-a-maximum

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's exactly it!